# JQuery template isn't processing - just spits out raw text

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am trying to work through Duncan McKenzie's knockout.js tutorial from MIX and there is a little bit where you uses a JQuery template each statement - here it is

```
<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <ul>
        {{each(index, friend) friends}}
         <li>${ friend.name }</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

When I try to recreate this it just prints the raw text from inside the unordered list tags once and that is it. i.e.

```
{{each(index, friend) friends}}
    <li>${ friend.name }</li>
{{/each}}
```

I thought maybe I wasn't referencing the template file correctly so I added this to my page (from an example found the JQuery site).

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
```

I am not much of an HTML/JQuery guy so sorry if this is simple but I have been trying to fix this for like a half an hour - I don't see what the issue is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you didn't call the tmpl function in another script tag.
Check out the example at the jQuery Plugin page.

{{each}} Template Tag
http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-each/

You might need to add something like this...

```
<script>
var friends = [
    { Name: "Mike", Languages: ["French"] },
    { Name: "Bill", Languages: [] }
];
$( "#friendsTemplate" ).tmpl( friends )
    .appendTo( "#friendsList" );
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, after adding <script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>, the problem got fixed. :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a couple of issues that are going on here. First I had the order of the  tags wrong. the knockout library needs to be last. Then I needed to get the right version of the JQuery template library. Here is how the includes in the script tag ended up shaking out.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Larry's answer is correct in other situations however I suspected that knockout.js was taking care of that part for me and indeed that appears to be the case. Once I got the script tags right everything worked. Here is the completed code, you can create a new MVC app and paste this in the home controller.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h3>Details</h3>

<p>First Name: <input data-bind="value: firstName"/> </p>
<p>Last Name: <input data-bind="value: lastName"/> </p>
<p>Name: <span data-bind="text: fullName"/> </p>

<h2>Friends</h2>
<div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul>
        {{each friends}}
         <li>${ name }</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function Friend(name) {
        return {
            name: ko.observable(name)
        };
    }

    var viewmodel = {
        firstName: ko.observable("bert"),
        lastName: ko.observable("bert"),
        friends: ko.observableArray([new Friend("Ralphie"), new Friend("Waldo")])
    };

    viewmodel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, viewmodel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
</script>
```

I found this documentation on knockouts site. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html see the note 5  "Using jQuery.tmpl, an external string-based template engine" I should have found this last night.

Thanks! Ken